# Replacing Weblogic with Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, apache-tomee

I am investigating replacing Weblogic 10.x with Apache Tomcat for dev machines and I'd appreciate any insight or recommendations anyone may have.

The reason for replacement is probably known to anybody ever trying to do dev work on a production webapp server monstrosity - to improve dev efficiency. The application is large (several million lines of code), legacy codebase, containing a smorgasbord of technologies (Struts, EJB 2, EJB 3, to name a few) and changes to codebase frequently entail doing a redeploy/restart of web server (even with JRebel) - which takes a long time (to the tune of 5-10 minutes). That obviously wastes time, introduces frustrations and leads to mistakes.

What I'd like to know is - is it even tenable contemplating this replacement?  The codebase would later on in dev pipeline be validated against a geniune WL instance but for the dev machines, I'd like it to be as lean as possible. This obviously won't be a trivial transition but I'd hate spiking a week on something that's completely impossible or, at least, absolutely inadvisable.

So obviously I'd need something implementing JavaEE spec (doesn't need to be officially validated - as long as it works :) ), so I've looked at possibilites and, to me, Apache TomEE looks promising. Geronimo is long dead, seems like, Glassfish is in limbo (?) and Jonas an unknown. Working under Java 8 would be a BIG plus (which TomEE 1.7 seems to support).

Lastly, we don't work with XA transactions (two-phased commits), so supporting that at least won't be necessary.

Is this a reasonable approach? Is there an alternative I am missing? Any experience doing the transition? Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: If you want something that implements Java EE, I'd go with [WildFly](http://wildfly.org/) (the open source JBoss).

Comment: How fast is it compared to, say, clean Tomcat or TomEE or Geronimo? Also - why WildFly?

Comment: I doubt you'll get much of a performance advantage by switching to TomEE. You do get the disadvantage of having different development and production environments.

Comment: I like the error reporting in WildFly / JBoss. You're the one who said *Geronimo is long dead*. I haven't used TomEE, and Tomcat doesn't have EJB. If you want a new framework, Spring Boot has a lot to recommend it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - well, Geronimo's last stable version is from 2013 and their most prolific commiters went over to IBM to work on Liberty Profile. Are you saying it's not? I honestly don't know. Yes, I am aware Tomcat is just a servlet container, but TomEE feels like a lean JEE implementation. I have no numbers to back that up, of course.

Comment: I don't disagree with your assessment of Geronimo, but it's open source - so it could come back. My opinion, if you want to continue using the JEE stack - stick with Weblogic or switch to WildFly. If you want a leaner development stack, switch to Spring Boot. Since I've run WebLogic on machines with as little as 64 MB of RAM (I worked for BEA in the early aughts), your claims that it's the problem seem specious. Several million lines of code is what I'd try to slim down first.

Comment: @quantum: What did you do to tweak WebLogic itself? Our JBoss EAP 6 (Base WildFly 7, I think) starts within two seconds, if nothing is deployed... other than that, I would also suggest to analyze your application startup, if Weblogic takes one minute to initialize itself, your app takes 9, switching the app server doesn't sound appealing to me.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I see what you're saying. Way back when, I've had dreadful experience with Websphere 5.x and 6.x - the beast took forever to startup and switching over to lean Tomcat (didn't need EE stuff) with some Atomikos sped up dev times tremendously as startup was improved by order(s) of magnitude. I have no prior experience with Weblogic and was out of webdev space for some years so I assumed changing containers would buy us some serious time savings. Also, the WL we use is really old so perhaps there is a gain to be had here if switching to most recent WildFly?

Comment: @slowy - I do not know, I am just exploring options and thinking out loud. What tweaks would you recommend? Do you have an url that would serve as a starting point for further investigation?

Comment: @quantum: I'd check the ibm forums first - I even heard during my education, that weblogic is a pain, and that was some time ago. Sooo, you are definetly not the first frustrated developer ;P. The benefit is, you can improve in the near future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

long-time TomEE user here. We have been using TomEE in production for the past 3 years. We started off with bigger SOA on version 1.7 (Java EE 6) and a year ago upgraded to TomEE 7 (Java EE 7) for microservices.

Our stack is Kotlin, JAX-RS, CDI, JSON-B, BVal, mybatis for db (pgsql and db2), elasticsearch, hazelcast, kafka, akka-stream-kafka and akka. TomEE makes for a nice, small application server. On startup and initial garbage collection I think it runs around 30m heap usage (or less). We are starting to run Docker on Kubernetes.

WildFly has some cool stuff happening and seems like they are more active, and obviously they have a huge corporate company behind it.

We concur and run the setup that Adam Bien espouses, which is not going uberjar due to the size of docker images, transferring 128M containers vs smaller 5-20M, running on a full application server.

I've tried out WildFly Swarm, it's cool, and there is also a hollow-jar deployment where instead of a fatjar, you can deploy a war (meecrowave also supports this and I think Payara micro too).

I would put TomEE, WildFly (and Swarm), and Payara on my list of app servers to use to stick with Java EE route. If you consider a different direction, prepare to wade through a ton of information, articles, blogs, etc. Akka-HTTP? Play? Scala? Spring Boot, which just runs on netty/tomcat/etc? vert.x?

So many players out there to choose from. Find one that you like and works. For us right now that is TomEE.